# List directories without erroring if none exist

Tags: find, ls, tcsh

I have a rather strict set of specs for a directory listing that I need:

1. It must list the directories in the current directory
2. It must list purely the basename (no "./", no trailing slash)
3. It mustn't error if there are none (and mustn't print an error to std{out,err})
4. It must be very lightweight
5. It must work under tcsh

I've got something working like this:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

But I can't help feeling that using "find" is overkill. I tried to do something with `ls -d */`, but I couldn't figure out how to get it not error (or appear to not error).

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you need the output? ls-style or one per line?

Comment: This is for a tcsh completion, which I think means either will work (I can't use the standard directory completion, for reasons I won't go into right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd say the find command is the way to go.

The `ls -d` approach has *two* problems right now:

- It shows an error on empty directories.
- It prints trailing slashes.

Both are fixable. [tr](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr+1) can take care of the slashes, and you need redirection to get rid of error messages:

```
( ls -d */ | tr -d / > /dev/tty ) > & /dev/null
```

See [man tcsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) for further information.